# Invert/change colors of nen html page within an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

what I'm trying to do is using an (external) html page within my page. Due to my page main color is black I want to change / inject the css of the iframe page. I'm not redistricted on the technology due to the page runs just local.

> e.g. [this page](http://abfahrten.hvv.de/c75aa7eb-c3b8-4505-80c6-794dbad90f9e)

should get a black background and a white font.

---

I tried a couple of ways. One idea is to read the html and `replace` e.g. the css file, but due to the mentioned page gets loaded dynamical via Javascript its not working (for me). Maybe this is a good approach? I'm open to other approaches as well...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

This looks very similar to another post, so [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19860937/1058612) or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25695330/1058612) might help. The gist is you might be able to send the parent's CSS to the child iframe via JavaScript like so:

```
window.onload = function() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(window.parent.document.querySelectorAll("link[rel=stylesheet]"), function(link) {
        var newLink = document.createElement("link");
        newLink.rel  = link.rel;
        newLink.href = link.href;
        document.head.appendChild(newLink);
    });
};
```

Comment: hmm I'm always getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of undefined at window.onload`