# Remove border and background color from CloudFlare Turnstile

Tags: javascript, css, recaptcha, cloudflare

I use the [CloudFlare reCaptcha Turnstile](https://blog.cloudflare.com/turnstile-private-captcha-alternative/) and want to customize the widget - remove the border and background color.

[image: Turnstile]

I think it’s possible with CSS or Javascript.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible unless cloudflare uses an i frame - which i am unsure you can style.
To style it go to your browser dev tools and find the div or element that has the style associated with it and get the class or id name and style it using css.
E.G:
div class="captcha"

```css
.captcha {
border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi, just inspect the widget and recognize it's an iframe. You mean it's not possible to customize it?

Comment: Here is some relevant information on this topic; you can style the dom inside the iframe but its not exactly pretty
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19858217/how-to-apply-css-to-inner-iframe-element-through-parent-window-css-class